# php вычислить разницу дат

Tags: php, mysql

Не получается написать скрипт. Смысл с в том, что мне нужно сравнить время которое записано у пользователя в бд, с текущим, и если разница составляет более 2 минут, выполнить запрос.  В данный момент выдает ошибку след:

> PHP Warning:  strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in 
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types in line 28

28 строка

> $diff = abs($currentTime - $date);

```
$currentTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 $connect_to_db = mysqli_connect($domain, $username, $password, $db)
or die(mysqli_connect_error()($connect_to_db));

$qr_result2 = mysqli_query($connect_to_db, "select date from users ")
  or die(mysqli_error($qr_result2));
while($date = mysqli_fetch_array($qr_result2, MYSQLI_BOTH)){ 
$need_time = 120; 
$date1 = strtotime($date);
$date2 = strtotime($currentTime);
$diff = abs($currentTime - $date); 
if($diff > $need_time) {
тут будет sql запрос

}
```

Comment: Ну так английским по желтому написано, что вы вместо строки подставляете массив, что неудивительно - достаточно посмотреть, как вы получаете `$date = mysqli_fetch_array`. Как минимум надо вот так делать `$date1 = strtotime($date[0]);`

Comment: точно. эт да, больше интересует вторая ошибка

Comment: А что вторая? Вы там из числа пытаетесь тот же массив вычитать

Comment: в цикле чтения из БД не должно быть других запросов. надо собрать это все в один запрос. например вы можете получить список пользователей у которых время просрочено на 2 минуты примерно так `select * from users where date<now()-interval 2 minute OR date>now()+interval 2 minute` и прямо к этому запросу можно подклеить другие таблицы и получить сразу то, что должен был получить второй запрос в цикле, или использовать его как условие в update и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался. Если кому надо бдует

```
$diff = ("0:2:0");
$curDate = new DateTime($currentTime ); //текущее время
$diffDate = new DateTime($date[0]); //время записанное у пользователя
$difference = $curDate->diff($diffDate);

echo $difference->format("%H:%I:%S");
if ($difference>$diff){
$qr_result = mysqli_query();
}
```